# How to create custom widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to create a custom widget. In the image there is two circles and in the circles there must be some other widgets.

[image]

I tried to use `Stack` and pray for it to be responsive but it didn't. Any ideas?

Comment: how should it response to size change ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using BoxShape.circle,

```
Container(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(width: 3),
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    // You can use like this way or like the below line
    //borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
    color: Colors.amber,
  ),
  child:Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text('ABC'),
      Text('XYZ'),
      Text('LOL'),
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image: This should result in something like this]

To achieve this in general I would recommend using a Column and then 3 Containers, one for each Circle, and something that draws the in-between part.

Comment: I just saw your replay and thanks for your time. I solved it with something like your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Custom widget in Flutter is built for Widget Reusability in App. Custom widgets in Flutter can be of many types Widgets are built to make your code clean and Shorter. It makes the Customization of Code Simple and Easy

// code

** Simple Button Custom Widget **

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class button extends StatelessWidget {
  button(
      {super.key,
      required this.buttonfun,
      required this.iconData,
      required this.textdata});
  IconData iconData;
  String textdata;
  VoidCallback buttonfun;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton.icon(
        onPressed: buttonfun, icon: Icon(iconData), label: Text(textdata));
  }
}
```